# symfony upload file without saving it on the server

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I'm using **symfony** and I try to import csv file to just get it content.
First I added the field importFile to my Entity(ps: the field should not be stored in DB):

```
  /** @var  UploadedFile  $importFile*/
private $importFile;

/**
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getImportFile()
{
    return $this->importFile;
}

/**
 * @param UploadedFile $importFile
 */
public function setImportFile(UploadedFile $importFile = null)
{
    $this->importFile = $importFile;
}
```

then I added the field to my formType:

```
   ->add('importFile',FileType::class, array('label' => false,'attr'=>['id'=>'upload','style'=>'']))
```

and in my view I aded the form field:
  {{ form_row(form.importFile) }}

--edit

I get the upload file on my view, but when I submit the form with ajax:
-- edit2

```
var form = $("[id^=" + "form" + "]");
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',

        data: new FormData(form),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {
          alert('rr');
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {


        }
    });
```

I don't get the imported file on my request:

```
dump($request->files->all());
```

it returns empty .

What should I do to read the file ?

Answer (score 1):

File inputs are not serialized by jQuery's [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. If you need to send file data to the server via AJAX, you have to resort to other methods.

A couple options are:

1. Using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) if your target audience's browsers support the [File API](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).
2. Using a jQuery plugin like [jquery-form](https://github.com/jquery-form/form) which can handle file uploads.

Comment: do you have any example of using the jquery-form for imput file field?

Comment: using formData I have also an empty result wheen I do dump($request->files->all()); although I get the file set in the data of the ajax call(see --edit2)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 4 has a out of the box solution for this.
Try using [FormData](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html#uploading-data) to upload files.